# Converstion of PS to PDF Using Ghostscript Out PDF is not Embedded Thumbnails (DoThumbnails)

Tags: ghostscript

Am using Ghostscript 9.07 for converting the Postscript file to the PDF file. The output PDF file is not embedded the thumbnail view (which lies in the left hand side of the PDF file small view). In Adobe Acrobat distiller it has the option to embedded thumbnail in the Joboption file if the Joboption having the tick mark then the PDF is embedded with Thumbnail view. In Ghostscript DoThumbnails is the option to do the embedding thumbnail view. But its not appearing in the PDF file.

command

```
gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf input.ps
```

Kindly let me know how to solve this problem.

Note: This is possible in the Acrobat Professional using manually doing the right click in the thumbnail view and embed All Page Thumbnails option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfwrite doesn't support creating thumbnails in the output PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Embedded the thumbnail view in Adobe Acrobat distiller will not work. Here is what you do. Go into your distiller settings tab and for your conversion settings select "PDF/A-1a:2005". Even if ImageMagic and GhostScript are 7 years old it should "convert" properly. The PDF/A-1b:2005 specification is actually known as ISO 19005-1B:2005. Adobe prefers to call the Adobe Distiller setting “PDF/A-1b:2005” and not use the “ISO 19005-1B:2005” description. The Portable Document Format (PDF) was originally an Adobe Systems proprietary format until it was released as "open source" on July 1, 2008 and published as ISO.

A free direct download PDF test file with detailed instructions to solve a "PDF Thumbnail Generation Problem" in TYPO3 CMS is available at Smargasy, Inc. "http://www.smargasy.com/fileadmin/media_data/community/Smargasy_PDF-Thumbnail-Compatibility-Test-File.pdf". The test file helps isolate the problem on systems that use ImageMagick and GhostScript as the image processing and conversion programs in a shared hosting environment.

Best Regards,
Michael Brice